# How to accurately check the execution time of a code segment

Tags: linux, x86, cpu-architecture, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I'm debugging a high performance data path on x86-64 platform. Its execution time may jitter, but its code is very short(might be 20-100 cpu cycles), how to accurately get its execution time?

Thank you.

Comment: Repeat 100_000-1_000_000 times and measure total time - when averaged, outliers will have less significance. Like how `timeit` does it in python.

Comment: Related: [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987) .  Also, 20-100 cycles is shorter than the out-of-order exec window, so it matters whether you're measuring throughput or latency.  On an out-of-order exec CPU, those aren't the same thing.  When you put your code in a loop to make it run much longer than timing overhead and pipeline length, measure latency by making the input depend on the output, or throughput by avoiding that.

Comment: Rather than try to measure the exact time I'd be more inclined to run it under Intel's VTune sampling profiler first and see how much time (and percentage) is spent in the code. section. I tend to use rdtsc for short timings (I know it is frowned on)  and enough  sampling repeats to get the jitter down. Any instrumentation you add disturbs things. Avoid MSC Profiler like the plague its instrumentation destroys high performance code. I think there is something similar to VTune in GCC and various other third party ones but I have never tried them.